# App <=> Service variable duplication and non-transparency

Tags: android

The separation of app and service is just frustratingly disgusting.

The app and service do not have access to each other's variables and data can only be made available to each other through the Messenger. This results in duplication and makes the conversion of PC to Android code an **absolute**, **absolute** pain.

Is there an API or some trick to make them share data totally transparently, or do I just have to settle for this cumbersome rubbish implementation (which is the answer that I am expecting)?

Comment: It sounds like you're putting your service in a separate process? This is not necessary unless you want multiple apps to share the service and want to conserve resources. A simple implementation of a service does not need to be communicated with through a `Messenger`. Some more information about your implementation would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [Services developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), if you haven't already.

There are a variety of ways for [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) and [Service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to communicate with each other. If you **bind** the `Service` to the `Activity`, you can share data.

You can also create a custom [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) object, which would let you share information across app components. A custom `Application` acts like a singleton.